# Is it safe to uninstall Google Play Services App?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, insufficient-memory, ram, google-play-services

I am using Andriod 2.3.6 Gingerbread for the last 3 years. For the last 2 months the **"Google Play Services"** app is taking too much memory, Now I want to uninstall it. Is it safe to do so? Does it affect other apps and/or the phone's basic functionality?

Comment: It is time to upgrade your software

Comment: @Rafi for some (old but still very good) phones, this is not possible (at least without rooting or other hacks)

Comment: Instead root your phone and uninstall preloaded unwanted apps.

Comment: I can understand your condition bro. I went through the same. In that case we have no option but to remove it (unless we buy another phone). Saves a lot of space. And most of apps work fine. The only problem is that you cannot install new apps or update the old ones.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Whilst you can uninstall it, it will automatically be re-installed on your device as it is an extension of the Google Play ecosystem and Google automatically updates Google Play services on all supported devices via the Google Play Store to ensure API consistency across devices and versions, and to deliver fixes and new features in a timely fashion.

Some apps may require Google Play services to be present and up to date in order to function correctly (or at all).

Comment: *"Some apps may require Google Play services to be present"* - e.g Youtube

Comment: Many new Google APIs are made available via this app.  Plenty of things will break without it.

Answer (score 9):

According to [Google](https://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html)

> Google Play services provides you with easy access to Google services and is tightly integrated with the Android OS.

And from the description in the Play Store

> Google Play services is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play.
>   This component provides core functionality like authentication to your Google services, synchronized contacts, access to all the latest user privacy settings, and higher quality, lower-powered location based services.
>   Google Play services also enhances your app experience. It speeds up offline searches, provides more immersive maps, and improves gaming experiences.
>   Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services

I wouldn't recommend removing it.

Comment: How to disable its growing "Data" size ?

Comment: If you open the App info for Google Play Services, you can press [Manage Space]. This will allow you to clear some of the data to a more manageable size

Comment: Please explain where to disable OR limit growing size ?

Comment: You can't disable or limit the size, only clear it once it has accumulated.

Answer (score 2):

Quote copied directly from the Play store decription:

> 'Google Play services is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play.
>   This component provides core functionality like authentication to your Google services, synchronized contacts, access to all the latest user privacy settings, and higher quality, lower-powered location based services.
>   Google Play services also enhances your app experience. It speeds up offline searches, provides more immersive maps, and improves gaming experiences.
>   Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services.'

I would leave it.

Answer (score 2):

All of the present Google Apps are heavily linked with the Google Play Services app. Uninstalling it will affect all of these apps, and, if you can't stay away from Google for a long time, I wouldn't recommend doing so. As mentioned in the other answers, Google Play services is the backbone of many apps currently on the Play Store. Many (I mean MANY!) apps are dependent on it.

Instead of trying to limit its usable data, you can occasionally try backing up all your data to a safe place and wiping/factory-resetting the phone once in a while. This will automatically cleanse your phone, and will definitely help on Android Gingerbread.

Answer (score 0):

I have uninstalled google play services from my Galaxy Ace running Gingerbread, due to running out of internal memory space, and it does not appear to have made any difference to the operation of the phone. I can still install apps, access Gmail, etc. I don't sync any data from the phone, other than Gmail. Phone runs much better now, much more internal memory and ram available. Phone is set not to update / install apps automatically and so far so good.

Answer (score 0):

Removed it! Saved around 30 mb internal memory which matters a lot because my 5 year old device just has 100 mb of it. There are no issues whatsoever, Gmail sync works & I can even update the only I app use i.e. Whatsapp. Already did once, no problems.