# How can I stop Google Play Services from updating automatically?

Tags: google-play-services, application-autoupdate

I have a OnePlus One with Google Play Services version 7.5.62 (1927436-438)

The most current version of Google Play Services is [7.5.66 (1939950-438)](http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/google-inc/google-play-services/google-play-services-7-5-66-1939950-438-android-apk-download/) which unfortunately has a bug of some kind that continually gives me the message `Google Play Services has stopped`.

Is there a way to prevent my device from updating to the newer version of Google Play Services?

Comment: Related: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/104842/is-it-safe-to-uninstall-google-play-services-app - Although I expect you're only really after a temporary measure until the issue is fixed (and you can then allow it to update again) so this may not be an issue.

Comment: @bmdixon I would like to avoid uninstalling the application altogether as I would still like to have the benefit of it.

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to prevent it updating, someone else might be able to help on that front though. In the meantime, have you tried clearing cache/data for Google Play Services? Are you able to uninstall it and let it auto-update again to see if it is just a glitch?

Comment: Yes I've tried that, a few other people have reported the same issue as well if you click the link in my question, although one has said that clearing cache and data worked. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Thanks for your help so far :)

Answer (score 1):

> If you've unlocked root, there's another option. You can move the latest working GMS (10.0.84) to system partition and block auto-updates by creating empty folders with the APK name.
>
> KitKat (tested):
>
> · APK goes to `/system/priv-app/com.google.android.gms.apk`
>      · libs go from `/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-{1, 2}/`  to `/system/lib/`
>      · mkdir `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk` `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk`
>
> Lollipop+ (presumed):
>
> · APK goes to `/system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/PrebuiltGmsCore.apk`
>      · libs go from `/data/app-lib/com.google.android.gms-{1, 2, 3, 4}/`  to `/ system/priv-app/PrebuiltGmsCore/lib/arm/`
>      · mkdir `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-1.apk` `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-2.apk` `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-3.apk` `/data/app/com.google.android.gms-4.apk`

(posted this on the »Google Play Help Forum« thread earlier)

Answer (score -1):

you can do this if you have a rooted mobile easily,  install rooted apps like lucky patcher or freedom. They have options for stopping auto-updates of google play services..

But it has risks of soft bricking your mobile.. so do it on your own risk!!

Comment: I have looked at Freedom and can't see any option to disable Google Play Services updates, only to disable updates of the Google Play Store, which is different.