# What permissions I shouldn't block with my Privacy Guard?

Tags: permissions, lineageos

I have installed LineageOS with "stock" version of Open GApps. I noticed Privacy Guard can control which apps have access to which information. I have changed nearly every permission to "ask me" and my system refused to cooperate (was freezing immediately after booting, [see similar problem](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/176231/changing-some-permission-in-privacy-guard-and-after-this-the-android-nougat-ca)).

Therefore, there must be a critical set of permissions that must be enabled (in Privacy Guard) in order for the system to work properly. What are those permissions?

I am using LineageOS v14.1 (Android 7.1.2).

**Note:** I do not want to troubleshoot my problem. I need an answer saying "if you block this information for that app or that information for that app your system will stop working". I have solved my problem by flashing the phone again, so I'm safe.

Comment: Did you apply these changes to system apps too? If yes, that may be the cause of your problem. If you denied Google Play services permissive for instance, it being a core component of OS, you can guess the consequences . Unless you have a deep knowledge of these permissions impact, it is best to leave system apps alone.For user apps  it is safe to apply community updated permissions ( pro version ) and fine tune as per needs

Comment: @beeshyams no "pro version" an, I'm afraid, no "community permissions". OP asks about CMs/LOS' built-in "Privacy Guard", not about Xprivacy :) But apart from that: full ack, only touch system apps if you know what you're doing.

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, I have changed system apps permissions, but what I did does not matter (see added note in question). I don't think Google Play services are necessary for LOS to work, since LOS is not shipped with GP services. Also see [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/104844/225393) - they don't say that GP services are crucial to the system, just for the extra apps. And they can be "disabled" even on non-rooted Android.

Comment: My mistake - was mixing up with XPrivacy. Sorry. @izzy. Thanks

Comment: @styrofoamfly Though GServices might not be essential, there's one problem in your context: they themselves think they're very essential, and are allowed everything – so if you forbid them access to something they see that as "hick-up" and retry until they succeed. Which they of course never can. Thus their constant hammering is slowing down the system. At least I assume that's what happens in your case: you cannot confirm/reject requests in the frequency they happen. "Ask me" delays the operation until user's answer (or timeout). Rather app specific than permission specific.